# Highlight item in menu that has href="#" option in "a" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make menu that will filter list on main page.
For example:

```
<div id="filters">
   <a href="#" id="all">Все</a> 
   <a href="#" id="top40">Топ-40</a> 
   <a href="#" id="top20">Топ-20</a>  
   <a href="#" id="top10">Топ-10</a>
</div>
```

So, the problem is that how I can highlight active item in this menu.

Help me or if there is another aproach to do it, please show.

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: Added JS and jQuery as no CSS solution for highlighting active anchors

Comment: what is active items , when and item is considered active ,is active items generated server side or user-action (e.g) click makes its active ??? clarify plz

Comment: yes, when I press one link, it should be active (by adding class 'active'). And should change filter options, so I haven't got an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you define "active"?

- If you mean the one you are currently hovering over, you can do so by
  applying a `#filters a:hover` rule.
- If you mean the currently selected page, you can only do so manually
  by adding a class name to the "active" link, or setting the ID / class
  of the `<body>` (that way, you can style multiple things based on the
  "current" page).

Update: Here's a way to select links using JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function select (x)
  {
    var a = document.getElementById ("filters").getElementsByClassName ("active");
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
      a[i].className = "";
    x.className = "active";
  }
</script>

<a href="#" id="link1" onClick="select(this)">Foo</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" onClick="select(this)">Baz</a>
<a href="#" id="link3" onClick="select(this)">Bar</a>
```

Comment: So, as I understand without linking to another page it is not possible?

Comment: And I mean currently selected page, by adding class 'active'

Comment: No, what I meant with the second bullet was, if for instance you are currently on the `all` page, either the `<a href="#" id="all">Все</a>` tag should also have a class to distinguish it from the others, or you could add an ID / class to the `<body>` tag, then apply one of these  rules: `#filters a.active` or `body.all #filters a.#all`, `body.top240 #filters a.#top240`, ... .

Comment: Yes, I know hot to do it with standard links, but this links haven't got address ('#'). So I don't know how change class 'active' when pressed one of them.

Comment: When you press on one of them, you expect a different page to load, for instance the `all` link would lead to `all.html`. `all.html` would then have a different link to the `all` page like so: `<a href="#" id="all" class="active">Все</a>`. Basically, the page needs to know itself. If you want to set the class without changing the page, you'll need to attach a JavaScript `onClick` handler to the links, then write a function that will set the clicked link's class.

Comment: Ok, I understand how change class of one link with JavaScript, but I don't know how to change one link to active statate, and another to be not active.

Answer (score 1):

You can somewhat achieve this with the :focus state.

```
#filters a:focus {
    color: red;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9PqNH/) as a quick example. It isn't perfect though

Comment: Doesn't do anything when I tried to change bakcgroundcolor or just color.

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem clear what you actually want to achieve. I seem to understand that you have a menu that changes content on the page, so no page reloads are happening, correct? But it remains not clear to me if the menu filters (shows less or more) content or if it switches content. In the second case, http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ seems to me an easy option (but this is also possible with less code).

Hereby an demo of contents that gets filtered with a menu: http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-sort-and-order-portfolio-plugin/full_screen_preview/2669205

I hope you can figure it out or can give more information.

More inspiration: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

`$("#filters a").click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass("active");
});`

Comment: @Chika I'm curious what you want to achieve. If it does not seem to be working, let us know. So we can give more accurate clues or show/put examples online. "We all make mistakes, and we all pay a price." ; )

Comment: no, it works with JS. So i just added some .js code that Thanix showed